# Saving PDO-data in array

Tags: php, arrays, select, pdo

i am doing this select:

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT clicks FROM table WHERE click_date = '".$current_date."'");
    $result->execute();
    $array = array();
    while ($user = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($array, $user['clicks'].",");
    }
```

But this returns:

```
49572940
```

But it should be:

```
4,9,5,7,2,9,4,0
```

Anybody could help me to fix this problem?

Greetings!

Comment: How exactly does that return `49572940`? It should return an array, not a number.

Comment: If that is what is returned from the query, then the `array_push` returns:  `Array
(
    [0] => 4,
    [1] => 9,
    [2] => 5,
    [3] => 7,
    [4] => 2,
    [5] => 9,
    [6] => 4,
    [7] => 0,
)`

Comment: ok but why does it return? : > array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(1) "9" } u know how to fix it?

Comment: Use `fetchAll` instead of `fetch` if you want to return a series of data from your query - it'll return everything as an array of arrays (and more if you want) and you'll avoid an unnecessary loop that way - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: https://eval.in/133456 returns what it should return!

Comment: `query()` + `execute()` ? should be `prepare()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT clicks FROM table WHERE click_date = '$current_date'";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
 $array[] = $row['clicks'];
}
//now echo and use implode
echo implode(", ", $array);
?>
```

because according to [PHP Manual - PDO::query](http://www.php.net/pdo.query):

> PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a
>   PDOStatement object

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fetchAll` to get all the values and also if you want to execute a prepared statement you have to use `prepare` instead of `query`.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT clicks FROM table WHERE click_date = :current_date");
$sth->bindParam(':current_date', $current_date);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

and after if you want a string with values separate by comma you can use implode as @jason suggested.

```
$str = implode(",", $result );
```